# How does 'be' + 'of' combine to mean 'possess; give rise to'?

Tags: etymology, phrasal-verbs

I already understand and so ask NOT about [the definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=to+be+of#of__23), below which I want to burrow. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. 1. Which [ODO definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) corresponds? What does **of** mean here?

> **to be of** = Possess intrinsically; give rise to

2. How does the juxtaposition of  **be + of**  effect/imply/induce this meaning?

Comment: Are you asking why *this work is of interest*, is the same thing as saying *this work is interesting*? The honest answer is that I don't know. But then I don't know why we use many idiomatic forms.

Comment: The tree is *made of wood*; the the glacier is *composed of ice*. To *be of* something is to *share its substance*, to *issue from it*. Why? That'll take some etymological digging, which I'll leave to others, but my money's on the *of*-of-origin; *Henry Downsworth of the Boston Downworths*, *Jesus of Nazareth*, and so on.

Comment: Do you mean as in "be of good cheer" and the like?

Comment: @Robusto: Do you mean definition 15 at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be+of+good+cheer? If you mean how 'be of good cheer' = 'possess good cheer', then yes. However, I'm seeking a general answer, and ask not about idioms only.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I am, but I seek a general answer on all apt uses, and not just that example.

Comment: "A general answer" is impossible when you ask about an idiom, for  ***by definition*** the meaning of an idiom cannot be derived from its parts.

Comment: You can't _derive_ an idiom's meaning from its parts, but in many cases you can explain the right way of looking at it so the meaning seems reasonable, and you can distinguish more and less reasonable ways of varying or extending it.

Comment: @BenKovitz Thank you effusively again. Not only will I revisit your answer, but will also paraphrase your comment above on how to interpret idioms whenever I question etymology in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its oldest senses, *of* meant something like “away from”, which *of* has lost but is preserved in *off* (“come off the porch”, “what a rip-off!”). It comes from the same Indo-European root as the Latin word *ab,* which roughly means *from* or “the source of”.

The general meaning of indicating where something came from, or coming away from something, is still roughly preserved in most of the modern senses of *of*: indicating the source or origin of something (cuisine of Russia), a reference point for something else (north of Boston), the characteristic period of time when something happens or exists (the Rite of Spring, flowers of summer), something that is removed (cured of the hiccoughs, deprived of liberty), the cause of something (proud of his accomplishments, sick of eating rice), the result of something (a doer of good deeds, the wages of sin, the product of effort), and many more, including the senses probably most relevant to your question: material (made of mahogany), belonging or possession (territories of the United Kingdom), and properties or qualities (the speed of the wind, hair of red). These latter senses indicate something about the object which explains behavior. If you imagine that the quality that the object is “possessed of” exists deep within the object, and its behavior is more superficial or external, you might have found the right way to see various other senses as extensions of the primary one.

So:

- *to be of foul temperament* = to hold, deep within oneself, a foul temperament, which could give rise to foul behavior; similarly, *to be of good cheer.*
- *to be of age* = to have reached a certain age, with the emphasis on the inner qualities that normally attend having reached that age.
- *to be of Russian descent* = to have an ancestral origin in Russia.
- *to be of use* = to be useful; to be among the useful, “of” the category of useful objects or people.
- *to be of the opinion that …* = to hold that opinion; to be among the kind of person who holds that opinion; to have many other, consequential opinions that flow from the deeper opinion explicitly stated; to have come *to* that opinion from many experiences; for you, that opinion came *out of* much previous experience and thought.
- *Time is of the essence* = An important aspect of the situation is that speedy action will be rewarded and dawdling will miss important opportunities. *Of* roughly indicates the source or inner nature; *essence* explicitly means what is most central or fundamental; so, to be “of the essence” means to be most definitely and unmistakably embedded in what is most central or fundamental.

I don’t think there is any one definition or sense of *of* that will uniquely explain these. Each can appeal to a different sense of *of,* to multiple senses simultaneously, or to the vague, general gist of it.

The word *be* just converts the prepositional phrase into a full predicate including a verb so you can use it where you need a verb:

> A man **of** foul temperament was hired to manage my department today. So, as of today, my boss **is of** foul temperament.

Comment: this is nonsense: "In its oldest sense". The comparison to Latin gives some context to infer how old you mean, but that's neither the only old sense, nor the oldest. Just compare the richness of the *po-*prefix in Slavic, nevermind that *u-*, \*Hew-, also *epi*, *up*, etc imply a richer etymology that that. Not to mention that German *von ... sein* parallels English, so this sense likely existed in Proto-West-Germanic, so that "of" in sensu strictu, as it appears in OE as the oldest form, already must have had this sense.

Comment: This is especially egregious when you cite "posess" (esse po(s)), that well matches the thought semantics and form!

Comment: @vectory It sounds like there is some misunderstanding, because I don't see much connection between your comment and the answer above. Maybe this is part of the misunderstanding: you quoted "in its oldest sense" and criticized the claim of a single oldest sense, but the answer says "in its oldest senses". Further clarification: I meant the oldest senses in English. These are presented in more detail in the [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/130549), which also explains the emanation of senses from "away from".

Comment: No, that's exactly what I'm criticizing, because if the same semantics exist in German, it's unlikely that this and that one arose independently in English and German respectively from a sense "away from"--which could only appear naturally convincing from the naive native speaker perspective, already familiar with the connotation, that henceforth does not explain anything.

Comment: @vectory Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Do you mean that a word for "away from [an anchor]" couldn't possibly expand to this kind of variety of senses independently in multiple languages? Are you aware that the same happened with [_dē_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Etymology_2_5) in Latin? It started as "down from [an anchor]" and expanded to become the all-purpose preposition in the Romance languages. I understand this to be a natural way for a preposition to "steal" the genitive case, hence something we should expect to see in many languages as their case systems weaken.

Comment: Ahhh, yes. I'm not entirely certain, because I am not actively in doubt about something like that having happened earlier, so it could maybe happen again in any stage of English. But you don't show any material evidence to that effect, so I remain skeptic.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Kovitz has provided plenty of good examples, to which I might add the clear difference between "You are very kind" and "That's very kind of you."

The former is simply a statement of your general temperament, whereas the latter means you have chosen (from—of—many different possible ways to treat someone) to be kind to me instead of ignoring my plight or treating me with contempt. The second statement is considered 'polite' because I have recognized your choice and am grateful for it.

Another obvious example would be "You're stupid!" and "That was stupid of you!"

In the first sentence there is no hope for you; in the second you can return to your normal intelligent self in the future.