# How did 'wan' evolve from 'lacking lustre' to 'pale' ?

Tags: etymology, latin

I wish to delve into the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. [What are some right ways of interpreting the noun 'lustre', so that the etymology for 'wan' feels reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

> [wan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wan) {adjective} = 1.3. {literary} (Of the sea) **without lustre**; dark and gloomy.
>
> [Etymonline for 'wan':](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wan&searchmode=none) Old English *wann* "dark, dusky, **lacking luster**," later "leaden, ***pale***, gray," of uncertain origin, and not found in other Germanic languages.
>   The connecting notion is colorlessness. Perhaps related to [wane](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wane&allowed_in_frame=0).
>
> [Etymonline for 'lustre':](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lustre&searchmode=none)  ... related to lucere "shine," *lux* "light" (see [light](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lustre&searchmode=none) (n.)).

I only cited Definition 1.3 because I'm guessing that as the literary definition, it's the oldest and so hasn't been coloured by newer meanings crammed into this adjective.
My problem: **lacking luster** does NOT equate to ***pale***, because lustre refers to 'glow' or 'shine', not 'light' itself. So how does **lacking luster** evolve into ***pale***?

Footnote: My friend saw the word 'wan' while reading [this](http://www.blogto.com/restaurants/easy-catch-fish-and-chips-toronto), and then introduced me to it.

Comment: The nearest I can get to the meaning of "lacking luster" is "dull". It's not clear to me, though, why you think luster would have to have had the meaning "light" for this etymology to make sense. The entry does not say that "lacking luster" = "pale", it says that they are two different, yet related meanings of the word.

Comment: Why do you keep trying to “rationalize” etymology?  You cannot ever do that.

Comment: Glancing through the first few pages of pre-1700 instances of [the lustre](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+lustre%22&biw=1170&bih=846&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1500%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1700&tbm=bks#q=%22the+lustre%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1500,cd_max:12/31/1700&tbm=bks&start=50) in Google Books, I have the impression it's more often used figuratively (of God, virtue, etc.), where the allusion implies a metaphoric ***source*** of light. Increasingly in later texts it's more likely to apply to (actual or figurative) ***reflected*** light.

Comment: The definition *"lacking lustre"* above in the etymology uses the ***current*** definition of lustre. The OED's oldest definition of *wan* is: "Lacking light, or lustre; dark-hued, dusky, gloomy, dark. *Obs.* Chiefly *poet.*" So clearly the OED does ***not*** think *light* means *lustre* in this definition.

Comment: @tchrist I should've cited the advice of user Ben Kovitz, which I now edited my OP to do. Do you agree with it: please see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571 ? His comment is precisely what I'm trying to obey, whenever I try to "“rationalize” etymology,

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you. I've changed my question to correct my error.

Comment: I don't see the problem. They're both about how things look, their color, in a boring sense. So they're not that far apart. You should be asking how ['blue' is cognate to 'yellow'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blue&allowed_in_frame=0) if you really want something that doesn't make sense on the surface.

Comment: @Mitch: I never knew about those two cognates! Should you or I pose the question?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I'm not sure what question is there other than the description given in the link, but if you can formulate something then great.

Answer (score 2):

The early use of *lustre* was full of light--literal and figurative.

*[Splendor Solis](https://books.google.com/books?id=hoZDAQAAMAAJ&q=%22lustre%22&dq=%22lustre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g8wWVfveL4SagwSpiYDYAg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjhk)* by Solomon Trismosin in 1582 suggests *reflected light* on the surface of metals:

> His definition of it is that it gives lustre to metals, and colour and
>   fragrance to flowers.

On page 400 of *[Certaine articles or forcible reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lustre%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1500,cd_max:1652&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22lustre%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1500,cd_max:1652,lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&start=120)* in 1600, Thomas Wright and ‎Etienne Binet suggest *refracted light* from a diamond:

> O goodly miracle to behold her so long time a Virgin in the midst of
>   the Court , as a Diamond among flames and not be melted, nor to haue
>   the lustre of its sparkling lessened'

On Page 169 of *[Du Bartas His Deuine Weekes and Workes](https://books.google.com/books?id=hQqj3BNtp9wC&pg=PA169&dq=%22lustre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BM8WVcjeLMiqggTkp4TYDQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADha#v=onepage&q=%22lustre%22&f=false)* in 1613, Guillaume de Salluste Du Bartas used *lustre* to describe the *light of the sun reflecting off of the moon*:

> The Sun there shifting in the Zodiack
>   His shining Houses, neuer did forsake
>   His pointed Path: there, in a Month, his Sister
>   Fulfill'd her course and changing oft her lustre
>   And form of Face (now larger, lesser soon)
>   Follow'd the Changes of the other Moon.

On page 7 of *[The Lady's Privilege: A Comedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=ELoQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22lustre%20of%20the%20sun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eNUWVZ3vEbb9sATLpIDwCg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22lustre%20of%20the%20sun%22&f=false)* in 1640, Henry Glapthorne used lustre for the shining light of the sun:

> ... subjects ought to offer,
>   With the sincere devotion that our priests
>   Do prayers to heaven, their hands as sacrifices
>   To their deserving princes, whose sole favours
>   Do, as the quick'ning lustre of the sun,
>   Cherish inferior spirits.

In 1613, Thomas Heywood used *lustre* for the metaphoric light of the face in *[A Marriage Triumph, on the Nuptials of the Prince](https://books.google.com/books?id=C6oUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22lustre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BM8WVcjeLMiqggTkp4TYDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATha#v=onepage&q=%22lustre%22&f=false)*:

> Such lustre in Adonis cheeke did move,
>   When he was haunted by the queene of love:
>   So looked Hypolitus when, clad in greene,
>   He was oft courted by th' Athenian queene.

It was quite common to use *lustre* for *the glory of God in mankind*, as on page 71 of *[Several sermons and discourses of William Dell](https://books.google.com/books?id=rcIsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA71&dq=lustre&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3dcWVfyIJ4r9gwSyh4CwBA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=lustre&f=false)*:

> They have a more excellent lustre then other men. One thing that
>   appertaines to the excellency of precious stones, is the lustre of
>   them. Now this lustre in the faithfull, is the glory of God upon them:

*Wan* suggests the *colorless grey of dusk*. The reflective *luster* of everything on earth diminishes, as the *lustre* of the sun decreases at sunset.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while most of the people associate it with "gloss," 1 in the following definition, "luster" can still mean something close to "light" (see meaning 2):

> **lus·ter** noun
>
> 1 a :  a glow of reflected light :  gloss, sheen
>
> 2
>   a :  a glow of light from within :  luminosity, shine
>
> *luster of the stars*
>
> *Blue Grotto of the magical luster* — Claudia Cassidy
>
> b :  an inner beauty :  radiance
>
> *one of those figures of spirit and light that leave an unforgettable luster in the mind* — Gordon Webber
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

I'd say, spare your time and buy an online subscription to this superior dictionary, really the reference for American English. It's only $30/year.

Comment: The OP already has OED access; why in the world would he want a small dictionary that doesn’t even have standard phonetics (read: no IPA!!) and is furthermore limited to one area of speakers instead of the whole world?  Plus it is not an historical dictionary.

Comment: @tchrist: ah, good for him then:-)

Comment: I agree that MWU is the best dictionary published to date in America. All the other MW stuff is crappy, but it isn't. There's just a lot it misses.

Answer (score 0):

Not every English word is from Anglo-Saxon. I favour Welsh "wan", meaning "weak".

English has more Brythonic words than Oxford philologists realise: "Mum" and "Dad", for instance. Cam, tweed and ooze are three more. A number of surnames are professions, but in Brythonic, for example, Goff = Smith; or animals: Brock = badger is one many will know.