# How does 'contingent' mean 'subject to chance'?

Tags: etymology

> contingent =  {adjective} 1. Subject to chance
>
> [Etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=contingent&searchmode=none) late 14c., from Old French *contingent* or directly from Latin *contingentem* (nominative *contingens*) "happening, touching," present participle of *contingere* ***"to touch"*** (see [contact](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=contact&allowed_in_frame=0)). The noun is from 1540s, **"thing happening by chance;"** as "a group forming part of a larger group" from 1727.

I don't excerpt [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40248?redirectedFrom=contingent) because it doesn't explain the above definition. I wish to dig deeper than the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy.
[What are some right ways of interpreting this etymology, so that it feels reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

How does ***to touch*** mean 'to happen **by chance**'? Suppose that X touches Y, and then Y occurs.
So X caused Y. So how does it make sense to say that Y happened **by chance**?

Comment: if  two things are in motion on their own trajectories they might touch at some point in the future or they might not and unless you take the time and energy to really analyze it, their touching will appear to be a  chance occurrence.

Comment: The Q is based on a misconception; and inadequate background research. Voting to close.

Comment: @Kris Please advise why you find the 'background research' `inadequate` here? What else should I've done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the question in the title, *subject to chance* it's simply because that's what the Latin *contingere* means.

> *Oxford Latin Dictionary* 1982 (via http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/contingere)
>   **contingo, contingere, contigi, contactus**
>   verb - conjugation: 3rd conjugation - voice: intransitive
>   Definitions:
>   1. be produced
>   2. happen, befall, turn out, come to pass, be granted to one
>
> verb - conjugation: 3rd conjugation - voice: impersonal passive
>   Definitions:
>   1. (PERF) it came to pass
>   2. it happens, it turns out

---

For the other question

> How does *to touch* mean *to happen by chance*?

You should have used the OED - it makes it quite clear.

The adjective form is listed as having two senses.

> OED
>   **contingent** ,*a.* and *n.*
>   Etymology:  < French contingent 14th cent. (Oresme), or < Latin contingent-em touching together or on all sides, lying near, contiguous, coming into contact or connection, befalling, happening, coming to pass, present participle of contingĕre to touch together, come into contact, etc., < con- + tangĕre to touch. (The n belongs to the present stem, the root being tag- , in compounds tig- : compare contact n., contaminate adj., contigue adj.) The subst. use is also in French.
>
> A. adj.
>    **I. From literal sense of Latin contingere.**
>   †1.a. Touching each other, in contact; tangential.
>
> **II. From Latin contingere in sense ‘to happen’.**
>    2.a. Liable to happen or not; of uncertain occurrence or incidence.

So know we can see that the sense "to touch" and "to happen" are different it should be clear that your question:

> How does *to touch* mean *to happen by chance*?

doesn't have an answer, because *to touch* does **not** mean *to happen by chance* it it purely contingent that the adjective form means both *to touch* and *to happen by chance* as well as the eight other meanings given by OED.

Once you get to the nounal form there are seven different definitions.

---

Etymonline's mention of  *happening, touching,* is not as clear as the manner in which OED shows the different senses.

I don't like Etymonline; I don't like the way they pile as much (which isn't much) as they can into a few lines without making it clearer what parts apply to what. OED on the other hand could do a better job of summarizing the different senses at the top of each page but at least the OED provides the information you need to determine what senses of the Latin origin are in use for each sense of the English word.