# How did 'legacy' evolve from 'contract, law'?

Tags: etymology

I was researching **legacy {noun}** which rechannels to **legate {noun}**:

> [legacy (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=legacy&searchmode=none)     
>       late 14c., "body of persons sent on a mission," from Old French *legatie* "legate's office," from Medieval Latin *legatia*, from Latin *legatus* "ambassador, envoy," noun use of past participle of *legare* "appoint by a last will, send as a legate" (see [legate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=legate&allowed_in_frame=0)). Sense of "property left by will" appeared in Scottish mid-15c.
>
> [legate (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=legate&allowed_in_frame=0)  
>   mid-12c., "authorized representative of the Pope," from Old French *legat* and directly from Latin *legatus* "ambassador, envoy," originally "provided with a commission," past participle of *legare* "send as a deputy, send with a commission, bequeath," from ***lex*** (genitive *legis*) **"contract, law"** (see [legal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=legal&allowed_in_frame=0)). General sense of "ambassador, delegate, messenger" is from late 14c.

Please help me dig deeper than the definitions, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. [What are some right ways of interpreting these 2 etymologies, to make them feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571) I don't quote the brusque OED.

Comment: Your answer is right there. Latin *legare* meant to *to send (as a representative), to bequeath*. So a *legate* is somebody sent, and a *legacy* is something bequeathed. Probably *legacy* in the sense of bequest was borrowed from Latin completely independently of *legacy* in the sense of "authorized representative of the Pope". (Especially since it was 300 years later and came through Scottish).

Comment: The dictionary isn't saying that "lex" evolved from "contract, law"; it is saying that "lex" is/was a synonym for "contract" or "law".