# How did 'to' and 'to throw' combine to mean 'adjacent'?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [adjacent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adjacent) =  1. Next to or adjoining something else
>
> [Etymonline for: adjacent (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adjacent&searchmode=none) =
>       early 15c., from Latin *adiacentem* (nominative *adiacens*) "lying at," present participle of *adiacere* "lie at, border upon, lie near,"
>   from ***ad-* "to"** (see [ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***iacere* "to lie, rest,"** literally ***"to throw"*** (see [jet (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jet&allowed_in_frame=0)),
>   with notion of "to cast (oneself) down."

Please help me dig deeper than the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but [what are some right ways of interpreting this meaning, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571) In particular,

1. How did ***"to throw"***  evolve to mean **"to lie, rest,"** ?

2. Then how did  ***ad-*** + ***iacere*** combine to mean the modern definition?

Comment: To "lie near" seems pretty close to the modern definition of "adjacent". I don't know where you get "to throw" or "jet", it just sounds like your making stuff up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the meaning of words expands over many generations, the thought process is not necessarily logical, but a little imagination helps us to understand how words progress from one meaning to the next. *Adjacent* appears to be related to *jet* through the Latin *iacere*:

> early 15c., from Latin adiacentem (nominative adiacens) "lying at,"
>   present participle of adiacere "lie at, border upon, lie near,"
>
> from ad- "to" (see ad-) + ***iacere*** "to lie, rest," literally "to
>   throw"
>
> (see *[jet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jet&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.))
>
> early 15c., "to prance, strut, swagger,"   from Middle French jeter
>   "to throw, thrust,"   from Late Latin iectare, abstracted from
>   deiectare, proiectare, etc., in place of Latin iactare "toss about,"
>   frequentative of ***iacere*** "to throw, cast,"   from PIE root *ye-
>   "to do" (cognates: Greek iemi, ienai "to send, throw;" Hittite ijami
>   "I make"). Meaning "to sprout or spurt forth" is from 1690s.
>
> *etymonline.com **emphasis** mine*

Among other things, the prefix *[ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-&allowed_in_frame=0)* means *toward* and *near*:

> word-forming element expressing direction ***toward*** or in addition to,
>   from Latin ad "***to***, ***toward***" in space or time; "with regard to, in
>   relation to," as a prefix, sometimes merely emphatic, from PIE *ad-
>   "***to***, ***near***, ***at***" (cognate with Old English æt; see at).
>
> *etymonline.com **emphasis** mine*

**Conclusion:**

Once someone throws something inanimate, it just sits there. Many years ago, my great-great-grandfather threw that big pile of rocks toward the old oak tree. Under his control, the rocks ***flew to the tree***. After all these years, the pile of rocks still sits there--***adjacent*** to the old oak tree.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be a reliable source, but my teacher of Latin explained to me that *iacere* over time assumed the meaning of its *passive* form.

So the active meaning of *throw* moved towrds a passive meaning of "be thrown" - and more specifically, the result of being thrown, which is *laying* somewhere.

Over time the reasonably aggressive connotation of the throwing or thrusting has disappeared. Hence we actually find *HIC IACET* on many gravestones. That text does not imply that the deceased was "thrown" into that grave, but rather, that a person "lies here".

(I used to think that it marked the spot where someone *fell*, but I have since been corrected.)

Now, if *iacere* evolved from *throw* to *lay* by its passive meaning of (the result of) *being thrown*, it seems no far stretch to see *adiacere*, "to be thrown towards someplace" to evolve in the same way: (the result of) *being thrown towards someplace* => lying close to or next to someplace.