# Etymology: 'as regards' and 'as concerns'

Tags: etymology

> [**as regards**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-regards?q=as+regards) = concerning; in respect of
>
> 2. **regard**  [with object] {archaic} = (Of a thing) relate to; `concern`

As per the above, because **regard =** `concern`, this question also applies to 'as concerns'.

I am guessing that **as** operates as a conjunction here, and **regards** a conjugated verb, but how did  **as + regards** combine to mean the above?

Please help me dig deeper than the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but [what are some right ways of interpreting the combination of the 2 bolded words, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

Comment: My intuition says "as regards" is a contraction of "as it regards", with the "it" referring to whatever the sentence mentions earlier.

Comment: Pursuant to bbc32's comment, I would guess that it's the same construction as the one in, say, *My grandparents attended church on Sunday, as was the custom.*

Comment: Etymology is not the same as expression origin. etymologies are for words, not expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The OED does not supply any pointers *as regards* etymology. But this is the entry which provides some interesting examples of its use.

It seems to begin in the late 18th century.

I am thinking that *as pertaining to* is a very similar expression.

> b. as regards, as regarded (now rare), †as regarding: with respect or
>   reference to.
>
> 1797   Treat. Police Metropolis (ed. 4) iv. 73   A distinction is
>   made, as regards moral rectitude, in the minds of many individuals.
>
> 1824   R. Southey Bk. of Church (1841) 408   That Church, and the
>   Queen, its refounder, are clear of persecution, as regards the
>   Romanists.
>
> 1848   H. Hallam Suppl. Notes View Europe Middle Ages ii. 78
>   Especially as regards the Visigothic and Burgundian partitions.
>
> 1884   R. Browning Ferishtah's Fancies 111,   I am in motion, and all
>   things beside That circle round my passage through their
>   midst,—Motionless, these are, as regarding me.
>
> 1885   Law Times Rep. 52 651/1   He was in a thoroughly sound
>   condition as regards intellect.
>
> 1920   R. Macaulay Potterism i. i. 5   He was one up on her as regards
>   life, owing to that awful business sex.
>
> 1937   Times 16 Apr. 23/6   And this in spite of the fact that they
>   were especially unfortunate as regarded the weather during the holiday
>   periods.
>
> 1976   J. Lukasiewicz Railway Game 120   As regards the maximum rates,
>   these are prescribed when there is no competitive mode of transport.
>
> 2005   M. Roach Spook 13   For millions of people, religion will turn
>   out to have been a bum steer as regards the hereafter.

Comment: Similar idio- and enigmatic constructions: _with regard/respect to, *with concern to, as it happens/happened, as a matter of fact,_ and many more. All seem to have the discourse function of subject-changers and/or  subject-reintroducers.

Comment: @John Lawler Contributors have been suspended for less.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not sure I follow what is going on here. An answer I supplied six years ago seems suddenly to have attracted the site's *glitterati*. And what's the point about being "suspended for less"?

Comment: Idio- and enigmatic ....

Comment: @JohnLawler If I say "I hold no views as regards what happened on Thursday", I would accept that "as regards" can simply be replaced with "about". But I am not clear as to how it is a "subject-changer" or "subject re-introducer".

Comment: @WS2 I was thinking of it in fronted position, heading a phrase: _As regards X, on the other hand, ..._. You're right, embedded is a different function.