# How did 'purport' evolve to connote falsity?

Tags: etymology

> [purport](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purport)  {verb} = [with infinitive] Appear to be or do something, especially falsely:

Etymonline's entry for the verb just redirects to that for the noun:

> [purport (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=purport&searchmode=none) 
>    ... back-formation from *purporter* "to contain, convey, carry,"
>   from *pur-* (from **Latin *pro-* "forth;"** see [pur-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pur-&allowed_in_frame=0))
>   + Old French *porter* "to carry," from **Latin *portare* "to carry"** (see [port](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=port&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)).

How did ***pro-* + portare** combine to connote falsity? I heed the Etymological Fallacy. [What are some right ways of interpreting this etymology, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

Comment: *Purport* doesn't mean *falsity*. Title is a bit misleading. The verb *purport* means "to claim to be but usually when it is not true"; that's why the definition uses the word "falsely". Other dictionaries use other words like "ostensibly" or "specious". I believe there is some semantic extension involved here where it evolved from "intend, purpose".

Comment: @ermanen Thanks; I ought to have written 'connote' rather than 'mean.'

Comment: I think this is fairly common to the entire set of synonyms here.  "Appear" implies that there is some underlying reality which differs from the appearance, otherwise it wouldn't merely be an appearance; hence falsity.  Likewise with a "claim", which is frequently absent proof/facts and thus suspect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the combination of *pro-* and *portare* had anything to do with the emergence of a negative connotation in the word *purport*. I say this because dictionary coverage of the term shows no sign that such a connotation was widely understood in contemporaneous use for at least the 255 years between between Elisha Coles's dictionary of 1676 and *Webster's Fourth Collegiate Dictionary* of 1931.

---

***The dictionary understanding of 'purport'***

Elisha Coles, [*An English Dictionary: Explaining the Difficult Terms That Are Used in Divinity, Husbandry, Physick, Phylosophy, Law, Navigation, Mathematicks, and Other Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n_5mAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP11&f=false#v=onepage&q=purport&f=false) (1676) has a single entry for *purport*, as a noun:

> ***Purport***, the true meaning.

John Kersey, [*The New World of Words: or, Universal English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHBUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP543&dq=%22meaning+the+Tenour%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrzf7JgrvyAhVDLn0KHZ68BbsQ6AEwB3oECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22meaning%20the%20Tenour%22&f=false), sixth edition (1706) treats the word similarly:

> **Purport,** Meaning, the Tenour or Substance of a Writing.

Fifty years later, Samuel Johnson, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1756) has entries for *purport* as a noun and as a verb:

> PURPORT, *s.* {*pourporte*, French.} Design ; tendency of a writing or discourse. *Norris.*
>
> To PURPORT, *v. a.* {from the noun.} To intend ; to tend to show. *Bac[on]. Rowe.*

Similarly, Noah Webster, *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806) has these entries:

> Purport, *n.* a design, meaning, tendency
>
> Purport, *v. t.* to intend, design, mean, tend, show

And Webster's full-size *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828) has these:

> PURPORT, *n.* 1. Design or tendency; as the *purport* of Plato's dialogue. *Norris.* 2. Meaning; import; as the *purport* of a word or phrase.
>
> PURPORT, *v. t.* To intend; to intend to show. *Bacon.* 2. To mean; to signify.

The 1864 edition of *Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language* hinted that the word *purport* might at times convey a sense of something potentially deceptive, but only with regard to a newly identified definition drawn from Spenser and labeled obsolete:

> **Purport,** *n.* 1. Design or tendency; meaning; import. [Examples:] "The whole scope and *purport* of that dialogue." *Norris.* "With a look so piteous in *purport*/As if he had been loosed out of hell/To peak of horrors, he comes before me." *Shak.* 2. Disguise; covering. {*Obs.*} [Example:] For she her sex under that strange *purport*/Did use to hide. *Spenser.*
>
> **Purport,** *v. t.* To intend to show; to intend; to mean; to signify. [Example:] They in most grave and solemn wise unfolded/Matter, which little purported, but words/Ranked in right learned phrase. *Rowe.*

But as late as *Webster's Fourth Collegiate Dictionary* (1931), the entries for *purport* give no strong sense that the word carries a negative connotation:

> **purport** *v. t.* To have as its purport or the like ; to mean or seem to mean or intend.
>
> **purport** *n.* Meaning.

The detailed comparison of *purport* (as a noun) to similar words (*meaning*, *sense*, *signification*, *significance*, and *import*) under the entry for *meaning* in the same dictionary doesn't indicate any sort of cloud hovering over *purport*:

> **Purport** is meaning esp. in the sense of general tenor.

But the *Fifth Collegiate Dictionary* (1936) tells a very different story:

> **purport** *v. t.* To convey or profess outwardly, as one's or its meaning or intention; to have the appearance, often specious, of being, intending, etc.
>
> **purport** *n.* Meaning; import; tenor; often, substance; gist.

So what happened between 1931 and 1936 to the verb form of *purport*? My guess is that the people at Merriam-Webster noticed the suggestive way that lawmakers and courts were using the verb *purport* in the 1930s—and as it turns out, long before.

---

***The legal meaning of 'purport'***

The [Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act of 1938](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Food,_Drug,_and_Cosmetic_Act) includes the following instance of *purport* (cited in the evocatively named case of [United States v. 306 Cases Containing Sandford Tomato Catsup with Preservative](http://www.leagle.com/decision/194478055FSupp725_1601.xml), tried in a federal district court in New York in 1944):

> The libel [that is, the government's plea for judicial approval of its seizure and condemnation of the cases of catsup] charges that the seized article is misbranded within the meaning of the Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act, 21 U.S.C.A. § 343(g) (1). If it is misbranded, it is subject to seizure and condemnation by authority of 21 U.S.C.A. § 334. Under the applicable section of the Act, a food shall be deemed to be misbranded "if it **purports** to be or is represented as a food for which a definition and standard of identity has been prescribed * * * unless (1) it conforms to such definition and standard * * *."
>
> ...
>
> The evidence clearly shows that the seized product is a food which **purports** to be tomato catsup, a food for which a definition and standard of identity has been promulgated, and that it does not conform to such standard in that it contains benzoate of soda, an ingredient not approved by the standard. It is therefore misbranded within the meaning of 21 U.S.C.A. § 343(g) (1) and is herewith condemned.

Here, *purports* means something along the lines of "claims on its face," "professes," "represents," "alleges on its own behalf," or "gives the appearance"—the meaning that the *Fifth Collegiate* attributes to the word. *Black's Law Dictionary*, revised fourth edition (1957) gives a distinctly legal cast to both the noun and the verb forms of *purport*:

> **PURPORT,** n. Meaning; import; substantial meaning; substance; legal effect. The "purport" of an instrument means the substance of it as it appears on the face of the instrument, and is distinguished from "tenor," which means an exact copy. [Citations omitted.]
>
> **PURPORT,** v. To convey, imply, or profess, outwardly; to have the appearance of being, intending, claiming, etc. [Citation (to U.S. v. 306 Cases of Catsup) omitted.]

The earliest law dictionary entry for *purport* that I've been able to find is from Alexander Burrill, [*A New Law Dictionary and Glossary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3Gs8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA843&lpg=PA843&dq=%22Purport+L.+Lat.%22&source=bl&ots=lcv9F4Eb5R&sig=ACfU3U1mVC1rJ17ikNRMUs8FM__m6905sQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjF65_sjrvyAhWVKH0KHbKCCoMQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Purport%20L.%20Lat.%22&f=false) (1851), which seems to be the source of the noun entry for *purport* in *Black's Law Dictionary* (the first edition of the latter was published in 1891):

> **PURPORT.** {L. Lat. *proportum*, from Fr. *pour*, for, and *porter*, to carry.} Meaning; import; substantial meaning; substance. The *purport* of an instrument means the substance of it as it appears on the face of the instrument, and is distinguished from *tenor*, which means an exact copy. MS. Buller, J., 2 *East's P. C.* 983. *Wharton's Am. Crim. Law*, 83.

And the wording of entry of the verb form of purport from *Black's Law Dictionary* seems to have come from *Webster's New International Dictionary*, second edition (1934):

> **purport** *v. t.* ... To convey, imply, or press outwardly, as one's (esp. a thing's) meaning, intention, or true character ; to have the appearance, often specious appearance, of being, intending, claiming etc. (that which is implied or inferred) ; ...

Of course, in law when someone purports (that is, represents) something to be true, the court pays considerable attention to the question of whether the representation is true or false. And as points of contention at trial, purported facts necessarily become matters of considerable controversy and close investigation.

But in the context of law, *purport* seems to have been used in the sense of "claim on its face" long before Merriam-Webster caught up with the usage. For example, Samuel Phillipps, [*A Treatise on the Law of Evidence*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wnE0AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22purporting+to+be+the+revocation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UhCJVZL1AsXKogTtiYK4BA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22purporting%20to%20be%20the%20revocation%22&f=false), second edition (1815) uses the words *purports* and *purporting* on multiple occasions, including this one:

> Upon what principle, it may be asked, is a party, by whom an instrument **purports** to be made, incompetent to prove it forged? In Watt's case, on an information for the forgery of a deed **purporting** to be the revocation of a will, it was adjudged by the barons of the exchequer after a conference with the judges of the King's Bench, that no legatee named in the will, nor any other person who is a loser by the deed, or who may receive any advantage from the verdict, can be a witness for the prosecution: ...

Here, the sense of purports and purporting is "claims/claiming on its face." And similarly, Henry Roscoe, Thomas Granger & George Sharswood, [*A Digest of the Law of Evidence in Criminal Cases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FBseAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA202&dq=%22purporting%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rxCJVeX-OozSoAT0oaTAAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22purporting%22&f=false), third edition (1852) has this language:

> And by the 5 & 6 Vict. c. 122, s. 25, in the event of the death of any witness deposing to the petitioning creditor's debt, trading, or act of bankruptcy, under any fiat in bankruptcy, his deposition **purporting** to be sealed with the seal of the court of bankruptcy, or a copy thereof **purporting** to be so sealed, shall be receivable in evidence of the matters therein contained.

Again, *purporting* means something like "seeming by all appearances." It is not a very great step to go from *purport* in the sense of "have the semblance" to *purport* in the sense of "have the appearance, often specious," especially after decades of legal usage in settings where the trial result might depend on the question of whether the appearance matched the reality.

---

***Conclusions***

In my view, the negative connotation of *purport* in present-day usage owes far more to the word's use over many decades as a term of art, in law, to describe an asserted but not yet proved claim of fact than to the English term's Latin roots.

Also of considerable interest is the fact that for more than a hundred years, dictionaries seemed oblivious to legal usage of *purport*, focusing instead on the ways that Norris, Bacon, Shakespeare, and Rowe (and belatedly, Spenser) had used the term in more-literary settings. Perhaps the legal sense did not penetrate into the vocabulary of society at large, but it seems odd nevertheless that dictionaries—and in particular, Merriam-Webster—paid so little attention to the way the word was being used in the legal system.

Answer (score 1):

Many verbs that involve information use metaphors based on transfer: you *give* someone an idea, you *pass on* a message, you *get* the gist. I believe this is all based on the notion that for information to get from one person's head to another, there's a conceptual form of motion that's initiated by the sender.

*convey* is just another word that refers to transferring, so it's not hard to see how this might be applied to statements. Why this particular one picked up the connotation that the statement is suspect is probably just an accident of history. Nuances like this tend to come and go over time, like fashions.

Comment: Have you any evidence that `the statement is suspect is probably just an accident of history`?  What bridges the semantic jump with the original meaning?

Comment: No evidence whatsoever, it's just a conjecture based on how language seems to evolve in general. Language is like fashion, there's little rhyme or reason why a particular color or style will become popular.

Comment: As with fashion, one way this happens is that some popular or influential person happens to use a word in a particular way, and others pick up on it. But while we may know which celebrities popularized the Little Black Dress (e.g. Audrey Hepburn), finding the person who used a word like _purport_ this way hundreds of years ago may be futile.

Answer (score 0):

purport: meaning conveyed, professed, or implied

thus in some contexts

purport = proposition

and

Propositions are the sharable objects of attitudes and the **primary bearers of truth and falsity.**[Wiki]

Thus, the connection of "purport" to "falsity."

Also:
**pur·port**
noun
obsolete :  **disguise, covering**

Comment: Thanks, but how did 'purport' acquire the negative connotation? You wrote `Thus`, but I don't see the cause.