# How did 'to rejoin' evolve to mean 'to retort' (only in English)?

Tags: etymology, french

I know of the 2 different homonyms behind 'rejoin'; I ask only about the one that means 'to retort'.

> [rejoin (v.2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rejoin&allowed_in_frame=0) [⟸] "to answer," mid-15c., legal term,
>    from Middle French *rejoin-*, stem of *rejoindre* "to answer to a legal charge,"
>   from Old French ***re-* "back"** (see [re-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=re-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***joindre* "to join"** (see [join](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=join&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>   General (non-legal) meaning first recorded 1630s.
>
> [rejoinder (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rejoinder&allowed_in_frame=0) [⟸]
>       mid-15c., from Middle French noun use of *rejoindre* (see [rejoin (v.2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rejoin&allowed_in_frame=0)). Originally "defendant's answer to the replication" (the fourth stage in the pleadings in an action at common law). For noun use of infinitive in French law terms, see [waiver](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=waiver&allowed_in_frame=0).

Please help me dig deeper than the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. Please expose and explain all hidden, missing semantic drifts and links. How should the etymology be interpreted, to understand how the semantic drifts abstracted and severed from the original literal meaning?

1. How did  ***re-* "back"** + ***joindre* "to join"** combine to mean the above?
What or who is **joining back,** to what, where, or whom?

2. The Modern French verb [rejoindre](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/rejoindre) doesn't possess the definition above. 
Does anyone know why?

Comment: compare **the battle is joined**.  also, in legal terminology, when a suit is slated to go to trial, it is said to be **joined**. These are examples of using "join" to refer to engaging in an adversarial contest.

Comment: As with @Mari-LouA I find your questions repetitive. You seem to be under the impression that word evolution is straightforward. You should think of it more like those puzzles where you have to turn one word into another in N steps, where you replace just one letter in each step.

Comment: Imagine an etymologist 1,000 years from now trying to explain why some word derived from _green_ has a meaning related to economical use of a resource (not necessarily related to the environment).

Comment: @Barmar I understand that etymology can be a puzzle, but do you mean that you reject the advice from http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571, which I'm trying to follow?

Comment: Maybe it's just an interpretation, but your frequency and style of questions seems to suggest that you expect straightforward relationships between a word's meaning and its etymology. It seems like you're just going through the dictionary, writing a question every time you can't see the connection.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Did you see my response to you at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/50720/law-area-51-proposal-commit?

Comment: The prefix **re-** also means: "again, anew, once more" (not only "to go back")

Comment: The advice which you provided a link, talks about idioms, not the origin of words.  I fully agree with Barmar's *interpretation*, it does seem you are overly anxious to see where the dots connect. Do you think native speakers are aware of the "hows" and "whys" of every single term? It's great that you study in such detail, and I'm sure it helps you to grasp the language, but sometimes you get lost in too much detail. You would do better to practice speaking with a native speaker and watch American/British daytime television, in order to hear how phrasal verbs, idioms, and proverbs are used.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rejoinder

> rejoinder (n.) 
>       mid-15c., from Middle French noun use of rejoindre (see rejoin (v.2)). Originally "defendant's answer to the replication" (the fourth
>   stage in the pleadings in an action at common law).

In other words, in French the word *rejoindre* attained a specific meaning in courts of law, separate from its general meaning (just like *dock* in English law is not a place where you tie up boats).

The English word "rejoinder" is based on that specific meaning from French law, not the general meaning. It has no connection to the English word "rejoin".

Comment: Sorry, but it’s unclear to me how this answers my question. Did you read my OP? I quoted Etymonline there already.

Comment: @LePressentiment - It means that the French *rejoindre* attained a specific meaning in French law, separate from its general meaning.  The English term is based on that specific meaning, not the general meaning.  Just like "dock" is English law is not a place where you tie up boats.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how did the etymons of *rejoindre* evolve to mean what you wrote (ie '"defendant's answer to the replication"). How and what does a defendant's answer **re-** + **join**?

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found: Origin 1425-75; late Middle English  rejoinen < Anglo-French  rejoyner, variant of Middle French  rejoindre, equivalent to re-  re- + joindre to join

As a French language enthusiast, I know the French verb 'rejoindre' means get back (to s.o), meet (s.o again), catch up with (s.o). It also means rejoin. But it doesn't mean 'reply', as you've noticed.

English and French have some commonalities, as they belong to the family of "Indo-European Languages".

However, they both have evolved over time and the words have acquired different nuances, I believe. This is quite normal and it shouldn't surprise anyone.